# Query Mongo on how many insertions occurred in last minute in capped collection

Tags: mongodb

Given a capped collection, how can you query the database every minute to determine how many new insertions have occurred?

For non-capped collections, one can store the value returned from `db.foo.count()` and compare it that value one minute ago, but for capped collections this method won't work once the collection has maxed out.

Comment: Not really possible. Since capped collection ensure natural ordering you can use the ObjectID time field to figure this out but that would involve iterating over all documents since there's no native way to query on specific fields inside an ObjectId. The easier (and frankly, correct) method is to track this seperately and update it from your app when you insert into the capped collection.

Comment: I think you mean to increment a variable in the same block where the insertions happen, which is the solution I'm pursuing now.

Comment: That's what I meant, yes. Note that there's no way to do this atomically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution that is automagic (analogous to what you suggested for "regular" colections).

The assumption here globally would be that there are no deletes, else the count methodology wouldn't work.  With capped collections there are automatic deletes, so that approach won't work.

There are many solutions of course but they are all rather manual so presumably no point further detailing here.

Comment: I'm not assuming no deletes, rather I am assuming deletes by specifying I'm looking for a solution for a capped collection. If there is a solution, why is there no point in explaining it?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a value stored somewhere (potentially even in mongo, in a document in another collection), and increment it for each insert.

If you want it to be the least intrusive you could even parse the output from mongostat, pulling the "inserts in the last second" field and adding it up for the minute.

What is your goal here?

Comment: goal is to tally tweets per minute